# .woff font files are not working good in modern browsers

Tags: html, css

I am using Lato fonts in my website,Mozilla and chrome are not rendering the font when i referred the fonts from fonts folder , then after I have used embedded woff  inside the css files which is working fine but the css files have become large sizes.

My question is ,Why the font is not working good when i am referring from external folder,but the same is working fine when i am embedding inside the css?

```
/* Webfont: ../fonts/Lato-Regular */@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato-Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are using location relative url`'../fonts/`. Use absolute, protocol relative or root relative url and it will probably work.

Comment: If you're using Lato, why don't you just use Google Fonts?

Comment: https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lato - can't you just generate it here and use the CSS link it gives you?

Comment: There's a good reason why he or she would choose not to have the font hosted at Google, as this creates another http referrer, which can slow down your website loading times. If every resource is sourced on the same server, it can make it load faster. It also affects your PingDom ranking.

Comment: @lee yeah ,you are correct.  we are not liking to referring an another server which may cause slowdown.

Comment: @Lee While it is another external request, they don't affect loading times that bad. Never had any issues personally with PingDom rankings when using it. Just another option that'll work

Answer (score -1):

Remove `text-rendering` and check the same

### Update :

Try this

```
@font-face{font-family:'Lato-Regular';
src: url('../Lato-Regular.eot');
src: url('../Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../Lato-Regular.svg#Lato-Regular') format('svg');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
```

}

Comment: I have removed and verified the same,it is not working.

Comment: I think you may miss the folder path structure. Copy and paste your font in desktop from your system. Jus Check this [link] http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. U can get the code and apply in your html file

Comment: @font-face{font-family:'Lato-Regular';
    src: url('../Lato-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Lato-Regular.svg#Lato-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}